# Wildcard redirect with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect this pattern with .htaccess:

```
https://www.example.com/abcdef1/products 
https://www.example.com/abcdef2/products
https://www.example.com/abcdef3/products
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/abcdef1/
https://www.example.com/abcdef2/
https://www.example.com/abcdef3/
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following, written as per shown samples. After placing these Rules into your .htaccess file, make sure you clear cache of your browser before testing it.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abcdef[0-9]+/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/products [L]
```